# PDF Snippets in Word Doc with VBA?

Tags: vba, pdf, excel, ms-word

So I have this Word doc with a bunch of ActiveX buttons, and whenever one of the buttons is pressed, a corresponding image pops up in a userform. It looks like this:
[image]

My problem is that each of the images that pops up is a screenshot of a portion of a PDF, but my users actually need to be able to select/copy the text presented.

Is there any good way to embed portions of a PDF file in a userform so that the text is select-able? It shouldn't be edit-able, just select-able.

Or, worst case scenario, what might be the easiest way to copy text from the PDF myself and format it onto a userform?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you loading the PDF in the userform?

Comment: I took a screenshot of each portion of the pdf, saved it as a bitmap, and I'm doing something like "Userform1.Image1 = LoadPicture("path")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using the image control for this if you want user to select the text from pdf.

Do this.

1. Install Adobe Pdf Reader on your pc.
2. Create a New Userform and place the `AcroPDF1` and `CommandButton` control and you are done.

To Add the `AcroPDF1` control see the screenshot

[image]

Next, draw the control on the Userform and place a CommandButton on the form

This is how your userform might look.

[image]

Put this code in the click event of the CommandButton1.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '~~> Change filename as applicable
    AcroPDF1.LoadFile "C:\Sample.Pdf"
End Sub
```

Now when you run it, the pdf will be displayed and you can select text. See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: You sir have answered now 3 different questions of mine in two days, and have provided like the most helpful possible answers each time. Thank you! I'll be certain to come back and upvote you when I have enough rep to actually upvote =/